# check if properties on objects are used

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I am working with Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper 8. I would like to be able to check my c# objects to understand if there are properties on them that are not used/referenced ie. find useages in batch.

I want to remove properties that are not being used and remove them.

Is there any easy way or automated way of achieving this?

Comment: Is this a coding problem or about a tool related with coding? I would expect a 7k-user to know what to ask here.

Comment: @GrantWinney I don't see anything about coding other than using some menus of some tools in your answer. If you think this is OK for SO then I can exaggerate it so that any question can fit here.

Comment: ReSharper has "Solution Wide Analysis" that will identify getters/setters that are not called explicitly/unused members/unused types. But that doesn't mean they're not necessary (e.g. reflection). I have a lot of setters on some entities of mine that come out of a read only database. I never set the value, EF does.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the "Find Usages" option:

- Open up the class
- Place the cursor on the property you want to search for
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (or right-click and select "Find Usages")

If the a property is not being used in the current solution, it'll tell you so:

[image]

I don't know of any way to run this for every class in the entire project / solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any easy way or automated way of achieving this?

[Solution-Wide Analysis](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis.html):

> Solution-wide code inspections are warnings or suggestions, that can be only detected by analysing the whole solution (**unused public members, classes, and parameters, unassigned fields**, suspicious type conversions etc.). These issues are highlighted in the opened files in the same way as other issues, and they also appear in the Inspection Results window when you run code inspection in specific scope.

Emphasis mine.

Note that ReSharper can only see explicit usages. If you use reflection in some way to access a member, this won't be considered by ReSharper. You can tell ReSharper about implicit usages with the [`UsedImplicitlyAttribute`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#UsedImplicitlyAttribute),

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about automated, but there is a right-click context command when you click on the property/function/field called "find usages", which will tell you if the code is not used.